# Getting a Blank space in top of print Screen AnjularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am working in AngularJS to Print invoice Page. Here i'm facing some issue. Getting a Blank space in top of print Screen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfmvV.png)

Here My Code

HTML

```
<div id="invoice" class="compact">
    <div class="invoice-container">
        <div class="card md-whiteframe-8dp printclass">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="invoice-date">10 October 2017</div>
                <div layout="row" layout-align="space-between stretch">
                    <div class="client">
                        <div class="invoice-number mb-8" layout="row" layout-align="start center">
                            <span class="title">PERFORMA INVOICE</span>
                            <span class="number">PI50/2017</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="invoice-number mb-8" layout="row" layout-align="start center">
                            <span class="hsn">HSN CODE:-</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="mybutton">
    <button class="print" ng-click="vm.takePrint()">Take Print</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@media print {
body * { visibility: hidden; }
.printclass * { visibility: visible; }
```

JS

```
 vm.takePrint = takePrint;
      function takePrint(){
        window.print();
      }
```

What i need to do to remover the blank spaces in top the of the print page.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHLIR.png)

Comment: its difficult to judge by the code, can you reproduce the issue on jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net or on plunker, http://https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Alana2597/bd1Ln8nd/ but clicking on button injsfiddle not shows print page

Comment: Its working fine here , https://plnkr.co/edit/6DTWaqrjHJ4sipmHowls?p=info

Answer (score 0):

CSS Should be

```
@media print {
body * { display: none; }
.printclass * { display: unset; }
}
```